# Oracle Query for join from two different tables without duplicate entries

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need a select query as per below requirement.

```
Table 1:

    DEVICEID  MobileNo DealerCode FNAME LNMAE
    1          1234     11         test test
    2          1234     11         TEST tESt

Table 2:

    DealerCode DEALERNAME
    11         JON
    12         DOE

Output:

    MobileNo DealerCode NAME       DEALERNAME
    1234     11         test test  JON
```

Please provide me the query for the same.

Comment: Somebody took the trouble to format your data so it was nicely rendered in SO markdown. Then your edit rendered it unreadable again. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "without duplicate entries"

Your data **does not contain duplicate entries**. There is a UID (`deviceid`), and each row contains different values for `fname` and `lname`. Okay, they are only different in terms of case, but Oracle RDBMS is case-sensitive (by default). So those rows are different.

Perhaps your application needs a unique key on `mobileno`? If so you need to specify a rule to choose which row to key and which one(s) to discard. So, something like this:

```
select p.mobileno
       , p.dealercode
       , p.fname || ' ' || p.lname as name
       , d.dname as dealername
from phone p
     join dealer d
          on d.dealercode = p.dealercode
where p.deviceid = (select min(x.deviceid) 
                    from phone x
                    where x.mobileno = p.mobileno)
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you.

```
SELECT MIN (MobileNo) MobileNo,
       MIN (a.DealerCode) DealerCode,
       MIN (FNAME || ' ' || LNMAE) NAME,
       MIN (b.DEALERNAME) DEALERNAME
  FROM Table1 a JOIN Table2 b ON a.DealerCode = b.DealerCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***distinct*** keyword in your select query. That should do.

```
select distinct t1.mobile_no, t1.dealer_code, t1.fname, t1.lname, t2.delear_name 
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.dealer_code = t2.dealer_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `table2` is a look-up table for `table1`'s `DealerCode`(and i assume it's primary key column in `table2` and has foreign key in `table1` pointing out `table2`'s `DealerCode` column). Then, you may try this without `too_many_rows` exception:

```
SELECT t1.mobileno, t1.dealercode, lower(t1.fname||' '||t1.lnmae) name,
       ( select t2.dealername from table2 t2 where dealercode = t1.dealercode ) dealername 
  FROM Table1 t1 
  GROUP BY t1.mobileno, t1.dealercode, lower(t1.fname||' '||t1.lnmae);
```